# Decoding json message inside of string

Tags: python, json, json-deserialization, jsondecoder

I have the following decoding function;

```py
def flatten_data(json_data):
    """
    Arguments:
        json_data (dict): json data
    Returns:
        dict : {a:1, b:2, b_c:1, b_d:2}
    """
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(json_data)
    return out
```

If I am giving the following JSON body input to this function;

```json
{
  "id": "123",  
  "name": "Jack",  
  "createdAt": 20221212,  
  "region": '{"country": "USA", "city": "NewYork"}'
}
```

I need to get the output as follows;

```json
{
  "id": "123",  
  "name": "Jack",  
  "createdAt": 20221212,  
  "region_country": "USA",
  "region_city": 'NewYork'
}
```

How can I modify my `flatten_data` function?

Comment: how are you reading the json data? Please, provide more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way with some modification to your existing code where the value is `str` because in this case, the **region** \has quotation `""`. So to handle this you can use built-in `json` module.

```
import json

def flatten_data(json_data):
    """
    Arguments:
        json_data (dict): json data
    Returns:
        dict : {a:1, b:2, b_c:1, b_d:2}
    """
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
        elif type(x) is str:
            try:
                y = json.loads(x)
                flatten(y, name)
            except:
                out[name[:-1]] = x
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(json_data)
    return out

json_data = {
  "id": "123",  
  "name": "Jack",  
  "createdAt": 20221212,  
  "region": '{"country": "USA", "city": "NewYork"}'
}

print(flatten_data(json_data))
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "id": "123",  
  "name": "Jack",  
  "createdAt": 20221212,  
  "region_country": "USA",
  "region_city": 'NewYork'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your "region" key in json_data provides str data instead of dict that is why you are getting the wrong JSON value. please try to make it dict.

try this data

```
 json_data = {
  "id": "123",  
  "name": "Jack",  
  "createdAt": 20221212,  
  "region": {"country": "USA", "city": "NewYork"}
 }
```